# Passing JavaScript variable into Django url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I have a dropdown menu that allows the user to select between three different use cases, and I want to pass that information to the next page.

```
<option id='b2c-menu' value="Delivery">Delivery</option>
<option id='taxi-menu' value="Air Taxi">Taxi</option>
<option id='hub-menu' value="Hub-to-Hub">Metro</option>
```

On select, I'm capturing this option as a variable in my JavaScript, and I'd like my second page to be aware of what the currently selected option is. To pass that, I'd like to do something like this:

```
<a href="page2/{{ selected_option }}"</a>
```

Is there a way to make my links dynamic based on my JS content?

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to get there.
One is to set the `location.href` dynamically on click. Something like this works well for me:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function(){
   window.location.href = "{% url '2ndlocation' %}?option=" + $('#myoption').val();
   return false;
});
```